# how to avoid cyrillic symbols in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am creating new records for one employee with Username, Lastname, Firstname as `"ѺѮѰѲѴA1kor", "Максим", "Максим".`

After adding Username, Lastname, Firstname as like above I am generating report in pdf.

But, in PDF I am seeing Cyrillic symbols instead of Username, Lastname, Firstname `("ѺѮѰѲѴA1kor", "Максим", "Максим").`

Please kindly help me to avoid this Cyrillic symbols while generating reporting in Python

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. Show some code.

Comment: What library, what config, what code, what system

Comment: While generating PDF I am getting output like belowUser name

■■■■■a1kor1
■■■■■■
■■■■■■

Comment: Ensure that PDF library support Unicode and that you are actually passing it a Unicode string.

Comment: Yes,  that Strings are Unicode. Could you please tell me which library file is going to support for this Unicode in Python?

Comment: Those strings *are* in Cyrillic (well, except the user name, which has some Greek symbols).  What do you see and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I am seeing lastname, firstname like ■■■■■a1kor1 ■■■■■■ ■■■■■■ . Instead of Greek Symbols I need output like username as "ѺѮѰѲѴA1kor" , lastname as "Максим" , firstname as "Максим". I want   to avoid this symbols while generating report in PDF.